# Webview in Android 4.03-4.04 with Google Book Preview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a webview in one of my activities that I load dynamically when the activity is loaded.  I'm just sending a string of html to it right now.  This webview basically loads an embedded google book preview. It also has a setTimeout that turns the page every 5 seconds. On Android 2.2 and 2.3 this works great.  However, in 4.03 and 4.04 it will load the preview initially but then it won't execute the page flip and none of the buttons work either.

Below is an example of the code to create the webview.

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1);
String html = getGoogleBookPreviewHTML(book_isbn);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Any ideas?